# Can only delete one picture in array

Tags: ios, arrays, uicollectionview

I am using a collection view to delete the array.  This is what I want it to do:
Step one: User taps the trash can
Step two: A collection view is bought up and user can just delete the picture by just tapping.

However my code strangely only deletes the first picture the user has tapped to and does not delete the other picture starting from the second picture.  I do not know why this is happening、my code for this delete process is

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"s:%d", [Trash count]);
    NSString *trashBin = [Trash objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"k%@l",trashBin);
    [allImagesArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.collectionTrash reloadData];
    [self deleteMyFiles:trashBin];
}
NSString *myFileName;
-(void) deleteMyFiles:(NSString*)filePath {
    NSError *error;

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
    }
}
```

Feel free to ask for more code

**Update**

do you mean this?

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"s:%d", [Trash count]);
    NSString *trashBin = [Trash objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"k%@l",trashBin);
    [allImagesArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self deleteMyFiles:trashBin];
    [collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil]];
}
NSString *myFileName;

-(void) deleteMyFiles:(NSString*)filePath {
    NSError *error;

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
    }
}
```

Comment: post your -(int)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section and the collectionViewcell returning methods

Comment: I have showed all my code here https://github.com/laryufk/Helper/blob/master/DeleteViewController.m Please take a look at it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try
[allImagesArray removeObject:trashBin]; if you want to remove trashBin from array.

Comment: Where should I put that? I want to remove images from multiple arrays. Please look at my whole code linked above for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reloading the whole collectionView you can delete the selected one by calling `-deleteItemsAtIndexPaths` of the `UICollectionView` class like below

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSLog(@"s:%d", [Trash count]);
NSString *trashBin = [Trash objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"k%@l",trashBin);
[allImagesArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self deleteMyFiles:trashBin];
[collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil]];
```

}

Comment: I have update my question. It still does not change, I only can delete the first picture that I tap and can't delete the second picture that I tap next.

Comment: @interdatega check it by placing a break point in this method or use NSLog to print the count of allImagesArray after the line  [allImagesArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: I have put a break point at     [self deleteMyFiles:trashBin];
 and it does not stop it.

Comment: @interdatega put the brk point and NSLog in -collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath: delegate method

Comment: @interdatega And check if the count is keep decreasing for each call of that delegate method

Comment: I don't get about the decreasing but it does stop when I put the break point there

Comment: @interdatega you can run the code in steps by clicking the next-step button in the lower left corner of the Xcode editor to find error or take those breakpoints and use NSLog to find if the count is decreasing on second selection of the item in the UICollectionView

Comment: No it is not decreasing but it knows how many pictures is displaying

Comment: @interdatega It should decrease by one whenever you select an item in the collectionView(i.e. removing an item).Removing an object from the allImagesArray will update the collectionview(animate removal of an item)